# Best option for replacing rotting redwood exterior trim

Tags: exterior, trim, carpentry

I have 12” painted redwood fascia boards rotting in places, and I'm looking for a smooth board to replace it with. Exterior kiln dried treated and primed pine has been suggested but would have to be processed (not available) also an exterior borate treated primed spruce has been suggested.

I also need to replace boxing around cantilevered beams to match other redwood boxed beams with beveled edges, so no cement board types. I need a smooth surface to match other beams. Any suggestions on best choice or another suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking because redwood is unavailable or prohibitively expensive? Is cedar available in your area? Expect SPF to last maybe 10 years unless you're in a very arid climate. You might post a photo for better understanding of context.

Comment: I agree if a wood product stay with redwood or cedar.  fascia boards are exposed to the weather and as far as wood nothing is going to outlast redwood, cedar would be next or go to a synthetic material. There are redwoods that are still on the ground and in good shape that civil war solders had photos in big trees , well that was years ago but I doubt they have changed much in the last 30 years.